# How do I save a handle of ActiveDocument to a variable?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I get the Windows Handle of an ActiveDocument in Microsoft Word?

I wish to save the handle value to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the FindWindow function to get the handle of the window in a currently active word application:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

The class name for MS Word is "OpusApp". If you have only the one Word app open then the following would return the handle to that window:

```
Public Function Test1()
Dim lhWnd As Long
lhWnd = FindWindow("OpusApp", vbNullString)
End Function
```

Note when you have multiple active Word applications, you can add the name of the window caption. For example if its saved as "Stanigator.doc", then the caption would read as "Stanigator - Microsoft Word". So:

```
Public Function Test2()
Dim lhWnd As Long
lhWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Stanigator - Microsoft Word")
End Function
```

The other API that may come in handy is:

```
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
```

**Edit:**

I was going to recommend the VSTO approach but based on this link that doesn't appear to be wise:
[Connect Issue: VSTO API support for MS Word Main Window Handle](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/492190/api-support-for-getting-the-main-window-handle-for-microsoft-word-via-vsto)

Comment: So there's no similar way as `Set ws = ActiveSheet` for Word VBA?

Comment: unfortunately you have to use the Win32 API's. I wish it were as  simple as ActiveSheet.hWnd. Another trick is to use Spy++ its comes with Visual Studio to verify your results. If you dont have it you could try http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17

Comment: Time to abandon my project then. I could perhaps get my friend to write the app in C# then. Gross. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion caused by the OP's use of the term "handle".  I think they just want to grab a reference to the active document in VBA, which is pretty straightforward....

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams pointed out, it's `Set myDoc = ActiveDocument`.